# Roxy Fileman upload directory

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm new with roxy fileman, I integrated it with ckeditor and all goes ok, but I have a problem with the upload path... I tried to change it from the conf.json but it always take me to folder called "1" at the root directory of my server (Wamp server)... and I also created a session variable called "SESSION_PATH_KEY" in order to set the path of the upload directory but also didn't work... below is the code of conf.json file.

```js
    {
"FILES_ROOT":          "",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "100",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"100",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "custom",
"DIRLIST":             "php/dirtree.php",
"CREATEDIR":           "php/createdir.php",
"DELETEDIR":           "php/deletedir.php",
"MOVEDIR":             "php/movedir.php",
"COPYDIR":             "php/copydir.php",
"RENAMEDIR":           "php/renamedir.php",
"FILESLIST":           "php/fileslist.php",
"UPLOAD":              "php/upload.php",
"DOWNLOAD":            "php/download.php",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "php/downloaddir.php",
"DELETEFILE":          "php/deletefile.php",
"MOVEFILE":            "php/movefile.php",
"COPYFILE":            "php/copyfile.php",
"RENAMEFILE":          "php/renamefile.php",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "php/thumb.php",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

Any on can help me please to set the upload directory to this "mydomain/files/"

Answer (score 1):

Change your path

```
"FILES_ROOT":          "/test-path",
```

Where test-path is a folder name which exists on root.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is old but ran into similar issue.

Look at:

```
"INTEGRATION":         "custom",
```

It should be ckeditor for your environment:

```
"INTEGRATION":         "ckeditor",
```

Then as already stated, set your path to folder:

```
"FILES_ROOT":          "/files",
```